# Scikit-image expanding active contour (snakes)

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

I followed the example from this [link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html). However, the contour contracts from the init points. Is it possible to do contour that expands out? I want something like the image shown. The image on the left is what it looks like, and the image on the right is what I want it to look like - expand out instead of contracting. The red circle is the starting point, and the blue outline is after n iterations. Is there a parameter I can set - I looked at all of them, but none seems to be setting that. Also, when referring to 'active-contour', does it usually assume that the contour contracts? I read [this paper](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~mchung/teaching/MIA/reading/segmentation.active.contour.2007.pdf) and thought that it can both contract and expand.

```
img = data.astronaut()
img = rgb2gray(img)

s = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
x = 220 + 100*np.cos(s)
y = 100 + 100*np.sin(s)
init = np.array([x, y]).T

if not new_scipy:
    print('You are using an old version of scipy. '
          'Active contours is implemented for scipy versions '
          '0.14.0 and above.')

if new_scipy:
    snake = active_contour(gaussian(img, 3),
                           init, alpha=0.015, beta=10, gamma=0.001)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.gray()
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.plot(init[:, 0], init[:, 1], '--r', lw=3)
    ax.plot(snake[:, 0], snake[:, 1], '-b', lw=3)
    ax.set_xticks([]), ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.axis([0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
```

[image]

Comment: You can try to set `max_px_move` to -1, but I have no idea if that'll work.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

What you need is **Balloon force** added to Snakes.

Snake's algo is defined such that it minimizes 3 energies - Continuity, Curvature and Gradient corresponding to `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` in your code. The first two (together called internal energy) get minimized when points (on curve) are pulled closer and closer i.e. contract. If they expand then energy increases which is not allowed by snake algorithm.

But this initial algo proposed in 1987 has a few problems. One of the problem is that in flat areas (where gradient is zero) algo fails to converge and does nothing. There are several modifications proposed to solve this problem. The solution of interest here is - Balloon Force proposed by LD Cohen in 1989.

Balloon force guides the contour in non-informative areas of the image, i.e., areas where the gradient of the image is too small to push the contour towards a border. A negative value will shrink the contour, while **a positive value will expand the contour** in these areas. Setting this to zero will disable the balloon force.

Another improvement is - Morphological Snakes which use morphological operators (such as dilation or erosion) over a binary array instead of solving PDEs over a floating point array, which is the standard approach for active contours. This makes Morphological Snakes faster and numerically more stable than their traditional counterpart.

Scikit-image's implementation using the above two improvements is `morphological_geodesic_active_contour`. It has a parameter `balloon`

In absence of any real raw image, let us create a toy image and work with it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.segmentation import morphological_geodesic_active_contour, inverse_gaussian_gradient
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
   
im = Image.new('RGB', (250, 250), (128, 128, 128))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon(((50, 200), (200, 150), (150, 50)), fill=(255, 255, 0), outline=(0, 0, 0))
im = np.array(im)
im = rgb2gray(im)
im = img_as_float(im)
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
```

This gives us below image

[image]

Now let us create a function which will help us to store iterations:

```
def store_evolution_in(lst):
    """Returns a callback function to store the evolution of the level sets in
    the given list.
    """

    def _store(x):
        lst.append(np.copy(x))

    return _store
```

This method needs image to be preprocessed to highlight the contours. This can be done using the function `inverse_gaussian_gradient`, although the user might want to define their own version. The quality of the MorphGAC segmentation depends greatly on this preprocessing step.

```
gimage = inverse_gaussian_gradient(im)
```

Below we **define our starting point - a square**.

```
init_ls = np.zeros(im.shape, dtype=np.int8)
init_ls[120:-100, 120:-100] = 1
```

List with intermediate results for plotting the evolution

```
evolution = []
callback = store_evolution_in(evolution)
```

Now required magic line for morphological_geodesic_active_contour with balloon expansion is below:

```
ls = morphological_geodesic_active_contour(gimage, 50, init_ls, 
                                           smoothing=1, balloon=1,
                                            threshold=0.7,
                                           iter_callback=callback)
```

Now let us plot the results:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
ax = axes.flatten()

ax[0].imshow(im, cmap="gray")
ax[0].set_axis_off()
ax[0].contour(ls, [0.5], colors='b')
ax[0].set_title("Morphological GAC segmentation", fontsize=12)

ax[1].imshow(ls, cmap="gray")
ax[1].set_axis_off()
contour = ax[1].contour(evolution[0], [0.5], colors='r')
contour.collections[0].set_label("Starting Contour")
contour = ax[1].contour(evolution[5], [0.5], colors='g')
contour.collections[0].set_label("Iteration 5")
contour = ax[1].contour(evolution[-1], [0.5], colors='b')
contour.collections[0].set_label("Last Iteration")
ax[1].legend(loc="upper right")
title = "Morphological GAC Curve evolution"
ax[1].set_title(title, fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Red square is our starting point (initial contour) and blue contour is coming from final iteration.